# Intermediate progress indicator on web

Tags: php

I have an `HTML` page, with checkboxes and Submit button. When I click 'Submit', I have a PHP script that takes every checked checkbox, and execute a script matched to that checkbox.

Because some of the scripts may take a lot of time, I want do something like a progress bar or other indicator that shows the scripts are still running. This should load on a separate page when the original form is submitted. When the scripts have completed, which might be a few hours later, the page should redirect or provide a link to another page.

I am new to `PHP` and `HTML` and would like to know how to show this sort of 'dynamic' icon or progress page can be made, as well as the redirect when everything is done.

Thanks!

Comment: Dare I ask what script is going to take a few hours to complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're gonna want to use AJAX for this, in my opinion. A simple solution would be to show an animation in jQuery and when the script returns the results, take it out. This is the line of tought:

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    $(this).hide(); // hide the form
    $('#loading').show(); // make a previously-hidden 'loading' element visible, possibly a div with an animation image/background in it
    $.post('/myprocesspage.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
        $('#loading').hide(); // done loading
        $('#done').html(data).show(); // Put the output of the script in #done element, and show it
    });
});
```

Of course, you should modify this to your needs. Please don't just copy/paste the code, understand what it does and how it works first. I suggest you look in the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) docs and read about how the functions I use work. Then, you can modify the behavior to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than redirecting to another page, you should submit the form using AJAX (a javascript scripting technique).  Check out [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/).